# How to label pushpins in bing maps?

Tags: bing-maps, bing, pushpin

Can any one tell me how to label pushpins in Bing maps for points of int interest? AM able to place multiple pushpins but unable to add labels to them dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the v7 maps control and APIs?

Check out the Infobox class and adding Infobox entities - these allow you to add a custom HTML block that can contain your label info. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg675208.aspx.

Alternatively with a pushpin you can specify the text field in the PushpinOptions object (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427629.aspx) when creating a pushpin.

Answer (score 1):

pin.setOptions({text: "label"});

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 7, try this little hack:

pinLayer.push(pinX);
pin1.cm1001_er_etr.dom.setAttribute('title', 'Push Pin Title');

This is an unpublished DOM.  And keep in mind if MS decides to change it, you'll have to find a different solution.